# changing the theme of a website from server

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api, themes

I'm designing a website with react, and it's requested that it has an infinite number of themes.So I know how to set a few themes in the CSS or SCSS files and then switch the classes to get the themes whenever wanted. But my problem here is , now I have to get a palette of colors from an API. Now I don't know how I can assign these colors which I fetch in the js file, to a CSS file, since that's where I need to define the classes.

Comment: You could consider using jss, or having a direct style tag inside your component.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create themes, one way to do this would be to use CSS variables.  Set each of your colored elements to use `var(--some-variable)` and then define it in your JS using `document.documentElement.style.setProperty(name, value)` after you fetch it from your API. This is roughly equivalent to using the `:root{ }` rule in CSS. In fact, you could use `:root` to set a default theme and then overwrite it in your JS after the fact.

In this snippet, I dynamically change the color of the `<p>` element from red to cyan after the window loads using this exact method.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--myColor", "#0CC");
};
```

```css
:root{
  --myColor: #f00;
}

p
{
  color: var(--myColor);
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
```